# Get values from set of html elemnts using jQuery when the corresponding check-box is seleted to send the values spring-mvc controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have table which is coded using div tags only(i.e. no table   tags). In each row I have same set of html elements as a check-box, a drop-down, another drop-down and a quantity spinner regularly. This same set of element is in 5 rows. I need to get the values of all the html elements in the specific row where the check-box is selected. I need to automate this function using jQuery and ajax and finally I need to send these values to the controller method in order to send to the database. How can I do this? (Simply I know this should be done when `$('checkBox').is(":checked")`)

here is the code for tow rows in the table in jsp page:

```
<div class="row item-tbl-row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <form:checkbox value="pizza" class="checkbox chkbxPkgCat" path="categoryName" id="chkPkgPzza"/>
            Pizza
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="itemName" id="slctItmPkgPzza">
            <form:option value="-" label="---"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="" id="szpr1">
            <form:option value="-" label="---"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <input class="qty-spinner" type="number" value="0" min="0" id="qtySp1"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row item-tbl-row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <form:checkbox value="Salad" class="checkbox chkbxPkgCat" path="content"/>
            Salad
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="itemName" id="slctItmPkgSalad">
            <form:option value="-" label="---"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <form:select type="text" class="form-control" path="" id="szprc2">
            <form:option value="-" label="---"/>
        </form:select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
        <form:input class="qty-spinner" type="number" value="0" path="content" min="0"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Should I use a for loop for each and every selected check box? Or else how to write a function and pass parameters for each element? Can anybody help me with this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code

/* call this method on click of check box */

```
var url = /*url*/;

$.post(url,
        {
          name: "Abc",
          city: "Pqr"          /** Create json of yout data **/
        },
        function(data){
            alert("Data: " + data);/*Return data from Spring Mvc controller*/
        });
```

/* Controller * /

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public String saveDate(@RequestParam String name,@RequestParam String city)
{
    /* Database operation */

}
```

Add this method in controller

Comment: This is not what is wanted. I am already calling an ajax function on checkbox click event for loading the data to those dropdown lists. I want to get the selected values of each html element where the relevant **checkbox is checked** and send them to the controller